# Is ListView ideal for single record/result with Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question in regards to outputting a single result in Flutter/Dart.

Most of the examples online showing the output of a result set show the usual **master page** (list of results) and **detail page** (pass the information and display a single detailed result).

I have a scenario where i want to show the user their own profile details, therefore no list required. I can achieve this using dart's `ListView` and display a single result. So my question is - Is this an overkill as there is no need to list the results (and loop over it). Is there a better way to show a singular result?

FYI here is my code for reference and can be used as a base for a response:

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('profile').where("uid", isEqualTo: currentUID).snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded (child:Text(ds["fullname"])),
            ],
          );
        }
      );
    }
  }
);
```

To clarify, this example returns a single result (only) and then loops through it. Is there a better ways to output a single result?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to use a `ListView` for the scroll effect, then you can do otherwise:

`SingleChildScrollView`

This widget is similar to `ListView`/`GridView`, but for only one item.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Text('Hello World'),
),
```

Comment: Hi Remi, thank you for your response. So how would that translate into code? I had a go with your SingleChildView but unsure how to output a single result (if you look at the code above it's dependant of looking through the results). For example snapshot.data.documents["fullname"] is throwing an error. Sorry maybe i could of articulated this better in my question.

Comment: Just replace the ListView by SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: I tried both: 

"return SingleChildScrollView.builder("

and 

"return SingleChildScrollView("

and both cause errors.